# what is the reasoning behind removing the limit in the exponent

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm studying calculus on my own. The lecture was talking about finding limits of *interesting* functions. Here is a concrete example.

Find the following limit:
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac{a}{x})^x
$$

Here is the solution:

Let $y=(1 + \frac{a}{x})^x$, then

$$ 
\ln(y) = x\ln(1 + \frac{a}{x})
$$
Now let's take a limit while $x\to\infty$
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\ln(y)= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x\ln(1 + \frac{a}{x})
$$
$\ln(1 + \frac{a}{x})$ can be approximated through a Taylor series as $ \frac{a}{x} + O(\frac{1}{x^2})$. 
So we get the following:
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\ln(y)= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x(\frac{a}{x} + O(\frac{1}{x^2}))
$$ 
which leads to the following
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\ln(y)= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}a = a
$$

Let's exponentiate both sides
$$
e^{\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\ln(y)} = e^a
$$

The next step is where I'm not clear
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}y=e^a
$$

How did we get rid of the $\ln(y)$ and got to just the $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}y$. I do know that $e^{\ln(b)} = b$, but what I can't figure out is how we got from $e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ln(y)}$ to $e^{\ln(y)}$

Comment: nice details for query; i upvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential function is continuous, so

$$e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ln y}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\ln y}=\lim_{x\to\infty}y
;.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I'm not familiar with the concept. Does it mean that because the function is continuous I can exchange the limits?

Comment: @flashburn: Yes. It may be more familiar in the case of a limit as $x\to a$: saying that $f$ is continuous at $a$ really is just saying that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(\lim_{x\to a}x)=f(a)$.